# Product matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

Создал функцию которая будет удалять товар из корзины в views.py

```
def remove_from_cart_view(request, product_slug):
    try :
        cart_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
        request.session['total'] = cart.items.count()
    except :
        cart = Cart()
        cart.save()
        cart_id = cart.id
        request.session['cart_id'] = cart_id
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id) #функция удаления товара в корзину
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug)
    for cart_item in cart.items.all():
        if cart_item.product == product:
            cart.items.remove(cart_item)
            cart.save
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')
```

и подключил эту функцию к html шаблону через urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from ecomapp.views import base_view, category_view, product_view, cart_view, add_to_cart_view, remove_from_cart_view


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', base_view, name='base'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', category_view, name='category_detail'),
    url(r'^product/(?P<product_slug>[-\w]+)/$', product_view, name='product_detail'),
    url(r'^add_to_cart/(?P<product_slug>[-\w]+)/$', add_to_cart_view, name='add_to_cart'), # добовляет товар в корзину 
    url(r'^remove_from_cart/(?P<product_slug>[-\w])+/$', remove_from_cart_view, name='remove_from_cart'), # удаляет товар из корзины
    url(r'^cart/$', cart_view, name='cart'),
]
```

html  шаблон

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<h3 class="text-center" >Ваша корзина</h3>
<br><strong>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td class="text-center"><strong>Товар</strong></td>
    <td class="text-center"><strong>Кол-во</strong></td>
    <td class="text-center"><strong>Цена</strong></td>
    <td class="text-center"><strong></strong></td>
</tr>   
{% for item in cart.items.all %}
<tr>
    <td class="text-center">{{ item.product.title }}</td> 
    <td class="text-center" >{{ item.qty }}</td>
    <td class="text-center" >{{ item.item_total  }}</td>
    <td class="text-center"><a href='{% url "remove_from_cart" product_slug=item.product.slug %}'><button class="btn btn-default">Удалить из корзины </button></a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>



{% endblock content %}
```

При нажатие на кнопку удалить товар, выдает ошибку

> DoesNotExist at
>   /remove_from_cart/smartfon-apple-iphone-xs-max-512gb-silver-mt572ru/
>   Product matching query does not exist. Request Method:    GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/remove_from_cart/smartfon-apple-iphone-xs-max-512gb-silver-mt572ru/
>   Django Version:   2.1.4 Exception Type:   DoesNotExist Exception Value:
>   Product matching query does not exist. Exception
>   Location: C:\Users\nsmex\Desktop\Online_Stor\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py
>   in get, line 399 Python
>   Executable:   C:\Users\nsmex\Desktop\Online_Stor\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version:   3.7.1 Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\nsmex\Desktop\Online_Stor\Stor', 
>   'C:\Users\nsmex\Desktop\Online_Stor\Scripts\python37.zip', 
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\DLLs',  'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib',  'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32', 
>   'C:\Users\nsmex\Desktop\Online_Stor', 
>   'C:\Users\nsmex\Desktop\Online_Stor\lib\site-packages'] Server
>   time: Пн, 7 Янв 2019 17:34:02 +0000

Как это исправить ?

---

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\nsmex\Desktop\Online_Stor\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\nsmex\Desktop\Online_Stor\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\nsmex\Desktop\Online_Stor\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\nsmex\Desktop\Online_Stor\Stor\ecomapp\views.py in remove_from_cart_view
    **product = Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug) ...**
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\nsmex\Desktop\Online_Stor\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py in manager_method
                return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\nsmex\Desktop\Online_Stor\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get
                self.model._meta.object_name ...
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Мне кажется, в юрле плюсик надо в скобки внести

Comment: На странице отображения ошибки есть ссылка "Switch to copy-and-paste view", позволяющая нормально скопировать ошибку.